# How do we display an image without using axis in matlab or any other option?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

I am working on some image processing stuff. I am displaying 2 pictures at same time using 
axes(handles.name)
Is there any other technique that is feasible to use for displaying images.

Comment: google "matlab display image"...

Answer (score 0):

`axes` itself doesn't actually display an image, that line simply creates an `axes` object into which you can place an image. If you want to display an image, you'll likely want to use [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html).

If you want to display two images side-by-side, [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) could also be helpful.

```
hax1 = subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(img1, 'Parent', hax1);

hax2 = subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(img2, 'Parent', hax2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.@Suever But actually  axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(grayImage, 'Parent', handles.axes2); % Display in axes2, NOT axes1.
title('The Image');

Comment: @Waqas_Ahmad of course it's displaying in axes2 since you're specifying that as the parent axes